# Storing temp data outside of SQL Server for faster access times

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an SQL Server(SQL Azure) table that is being queried at a high rate, but gets updated only few times a month.

I wonder what options do I have that can cache the result set on the application side so that it will not have to hit SQL Server all the time.

Comment: There are several options, but some of them will depend on what you are using on the application side (ASP.NET MVC? Node? Are you using an ORM like EF or NH?)

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 4 running on Azure and EF with SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to just `[OutputCache]` the action methods which return the views. You may even be able to get away with SQL Dependency caching, though not sure if this works with Azure.

Another option is to try implementing [a second-level cache for EF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/435142/Entity-Framework-Second-Level-Caching-with-DbConte).

Another option is to have an entirely different read model. This way, you wouldn't query against the table, but something else that is closer to IIS and/or faster than SQL Azure (like NoSQL or JSON from Azure cache).